# If $0\stackrel{f}\rightarrow V \stackrel{g}\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, then $V = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

> Show that if $0\stackrel{f}\rightarrow V \stackrel{g}\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of vector spaces over a field $K$, then $V = 0$.

I know that $\ker(g) = \text{im}(f)$, but how can I get that $V=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $\ker g=V$, since $g(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$. On the other hand, $\text{im}f=0 $, since the image of the zero vector space is always zero. The result follows.

Comment: Since $g(v) = 0$ for all $v in V$ then $dim(im(g)) = 0$ and we know that $dim(V) = dim(im(g)) + dim(ker(g)) = dim(ker(g))$ and because the kernel is a subspace of $V$ it follows that $ker(g) = V$? Is there a simple idea to see the implication?

Comment: $v\in \ker g\iff g(v)=0$. On the other hand, $g(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$. Hence, $\ker g=V$.